# Abort trap 6: Freeing unallocated pointer

Tags: c, linked-list

Here is code to destroy a circularly linked list. When it runs, it produces an abort trap 6: pointer being freed was not allocated

```
NODE *roamer = list->head;
        do{
            NODE *oldRoamer = roamer;
            roamer = roamer->next;
            printf("freeing prev");
            free(oldRoamer);
            printf("prev freed");
        }while (roamer != NULL);
```

The program prints both printf statements a bunch of times, but then gives the error just after printing "freeing prev".

Comment: Note that so far all the answers below will ultimately require evaluating the value of a pointer that is no longer viable (`list->head`) once the first node is freed (the one `list->head` referred to). By the strictest interpretation of the language standard, it is therefore no longer *evaluable* either, not just non-dereferenceable. I've yet to see an implementation where it actually makes a difference, but it none-the-less isn't purely standard compliant to do so. It is possible to do this within those limits, but it may not be entirely intuitive at first.

Comment: Sample of one such algorithm I mentioned above: [See it live](http://ideone.com/11rmnk)

Comment: simple way: roamer = list->head->next; list->head->next = null;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's CIRCULAR. That means the last item points to the first, which has already been freed.

```
do
    ....
while (roamer != list->head);
```

Comment: so if the head had been freed, isn't list->head NULL?

Comment: @ChristianAyscue no. you never set it as such. `free(ptr)` leaves a dangling pointer in `ptr`.

Comment: you'd logically set list->head to NULL after your loop.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional used to stop the loop is incorrect.

```
NODE *roamer = list->head;
do {
   NODE *oldRoamer = roamer;
   roamer = roamer->next;
   printf("freeing prev");
   free(oldRoamer);
   printf("prev freed");
} while (roamer != list->head);
// Stop when roamer reaches back to head
```